# "pageview" term in web world

Tags: terminology, pageviews

I'm building a web app and need to implement "how many times the item is being viewed". What is the term of "being viewed"? is it every time someone goes to that page or being counted once for the same session?  please help

Comment: Ask for clarification from whoever wrote/gave you the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two types of definitions for the term 'page view'.

From a technical point of view, it can represent the **times the page has been requested** by a web browser. This can be interesting information if you have to optimize your application's code, but it has little to no value for the visitors of your site.

The thing that visitors are more likely to be interested in, is the **number of people that have viewed the page**. Although you cannot exactly measure this, you can get a good approximation by treating multiple requests within a session as a single view. If your application allows visitors to log in, you can even treat all requests by a single user as one page view, regardless of when the requests were made.

Since you will be presenting the number of views on the page, you'll probably want the number of people that have viewed the page, rather than the number of requests.

Comment: sorry.. another scenario.. if the first time the unauthenticated user navigates the page and then after 5 minutes the user logs in and navigates to the same page.. would you count it as twice or still once?

Comment: If the unauthenticated view occurs in the same session as the login, you can attribute the view to the logged in user, thus counting it as a single view. But when both views occur in separate sessions, I'd count them as two separate views. Remember that it's not an exact science, as you cannot tell who's actually sitting behind the monitor ;)

Answer (score 3):

That depends on whether you want to track **Page Views** or **Number of Visitors.**.

Though StackOverflow seems to use "Views" per visitor, not actual Page Views.

Comment: say.. if I'm selling an item on my web.. I need to track how many times the item has been viewed. Would you recommend the best way how to track this? would it be better to user per session or per visit (regardless who the user is) or anything else?

Comment: I'd use actual Page Views instead of Per User views, it should definately help with sales :)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime someone goes to that page.

Assuming you have a database for items, or whatever, you'll need to have a column that represents the view. On every page load you will increment that counter.

Answer (score 0):

It means the number of times a page has been viewed. It is not tied to a user session. It is more related to the application scope.